# Powershell Command inside CMD

Tags: powershell, script

I have a CMD bat file which asks users to paste in the path to their log files from other programs that have run.

Once they do I my script scans the logs in the pasted in path for certain text, warnings, errors etc

So i have the below code which scans any files in the directory for the pattern WARNING: and outputs a file called `psout.txt` which shows the offending line text and number where it occurred.

```
powershell "Get-Content *.* | Select-String -Pattern WARNING: | Select-Object LineNumber, Line | out-file -filepath psout.txt"
```

However, as there can be multiple logs, is there a way to modify this line of code to show the filename beside the line number, I have tried `basename` and other variations but just can't get it.

I have seen that `filename` should do the job but while it returns a value its always the value of "Input Stream"

Any ideas ?

Comment: Any particular reason to use a batch file that starts powershell, and not just create a powershell script (.ps1) and simply run that? Everything you can do in batch can be done in powershell anyways.

Comment: Hi there, not really I am just more comfortable with CMD, and then i bring in PS commands if i need them etc.....

Comment: The biggest problem with this approach is that a powershell script itself is far easier to work with and can do much more once in a .ps1 script. Now you just have oneliners

Comment: I agree but I guess for me anyway the prompting that goes before this is simpler for me in CMD....plus i will have other applications that will be interacting with this and they work smoother with CMD lets say

Comment: Seems i just figured it out with a bit more googling :-).....will update the post

Answer (score 2):

So it seems a slight adjustment is all that is needed:

`powershell "Get-Childitem -recurse | Select-String -Pattern WARNING: | Select-Object filename,LineNumber, Line | out-file -filepath '[MyPath]\psout.txt'"`

Comment: It looks like you found the answer, that's great. Could you mark your answer as accepted? This shows other people your question has the answer you were looking for and will help others that have a similar issue.